# How to show "product not available" message on product page template created with Elementor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I have created a product page template using Elementor page builder. I have also created custom field for the product where I select the months in which product is not available for sale code I am using is mentioned below. My issue is when I am using theme default template it does show the message "product not available" if its not available for that selected month but when I use elementor created template it does not show the error message and I am not able to find a way to show message there. If anyone knows how to do it please let me know.

here is the code.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback( $purchasable, $product ) {
  $months = (array) get_field('availability', $product->get_id());
      $purchasable = in_array( date('F'), $months ) ? false : $purchasable;
    return $purchasable;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'unavailable_product_display_message', 20 );
function unavailable_product_display_message() {
    global $product;
    if(! $product->is_purchasable() ){
        echo '<p style="color:#e00000;">' . __("This product is currently unavailable.") . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are useing short code for add  to cart it will automatically show message there

Comment: Not using shortcode using Elementor add to cart widget and it does not show the message.

Comment: [add_to_cart id="99"]  replace id with  your product id

Comment: Its product page template that apply on all the products.